Cloudflare with GCP load balancer give "Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue" error
I am using Cloudflare with GCP. Cloudflare proxies my load balancer.
When making a request using Postman or using curl, I get this error
Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue

In the browser, it works perfectly.
If instead, I make a request directly to my load balancer with curl, it works.
So problems seems to be with Cloudflare
Some say its the due to Bot prevention. How can I use Postman and Curl to test my endpoints without removing this protection?

Here are a few steps you can try to resolve the issue:
Enable JavaScript and Cookies: Make sure that JavaScript is enabled in your browser settings and that your browser allows cookies from the GCP domain.
Clear Browser Cache and Cookies: Sometimes, clearing your browser's cache and cookies can resolve the issue. Try clearing them and then reloading the GCP console.
Try a Different Browser: If clearing the cache and cookies doesn't work, try accessing the GCP console using a different browser to see if the issue persists.
Disable Browser Extensions: Some browser extensions can interfere with the functionality of websites. Try disabling any extensions that might be causing conflicts with the GCP console.
Check for Service Outages: Sometimes, the issue might be caused by a service outage on the GCP side. Check the GCP status page or the Google Cloud Status Dashboard to see if there are any ongoing issues.
